# Running JavaScript on Java with native functions?

Tags: javascript, java, eval

I am building a program in Java and I want to make users able to create plugins in JavaScript. I need a way to make native functions in a "standard lib" so people can use the methods inside the program.
Also I want to make an event system, so this means calling functions inside the JavaScript plugin. How could I achieve this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino

Comment: Can someone please explain the downvotes to the question? I know it's kinda broad, but it actually specifies conditions and such...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run java-script in java you may use Rhino library in java 1.7

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino

example:

https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/blob/master/examples/Control.java

or Nashorn in java 1.8

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html

example:

http://www.infoworld.com/article/2607426/application-development/nashorn--javascript-made-great-in-java-8.html?page=2

Comment: Thank you! Did not know there is an interpreter in the jdk.